# Python for-loop assignment updating/missing/ghost values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variable-assignment

### Edit:

I have solved the problem, but I'm still not sure of the specifics. It *appears* that the issue lies in an inconsistency between `if` conditionals and ternary operators. `item` is considered `True` when tested as such: `if item:` as long as it exists. However, it is considered `False` when tested as such: `"xyz" if item else "abc"`.

I'm not sure if this is intended or unintended behavior. Or perhaps there are some underlying nuances that elude me. Hence, posting this as an edit rather than as an answer.

---

I have the following code:

```
for item in item_list[:]:
    item.attribute = next((i for i in item_list if i.id == func(item.id)), item(-1))
    
    print(item.attribute.id if item.attribute else "None")
    print(item.attribute is None)
    print(item.id)
    print(func(item.id))
    print(type(i.id) is int)
```

`func` is a function that specifically returns a number cast as an `int`. `item(x)` creates an instance of `item` whose `.id` is equal to `x`.

What I expect: the first print statement yields the `.id` value of the appropriate `item`.

What actually happens: the first `item` in `list` works as expected. For all other `item`s, the first print statement yields `"None"`

Why this is confusing: in all flawed cases, the second print statement yields `"False"` (I have tried changing `item.attribute is None` to `item.attribute == None`). The third and fourth print statements show that every `func(match.id)` has a value that matches some `match.id`. The fifth (last) print statement verifies that every `match.id` is in fact an `int`. I have verified externally that the list *is* entirely formed prior to this function. There is no manipulation of the `items` happening simultaneously, because there is no manipulation of the `items` elsewhere whatsoever.

So basically, the comparison I've created **must succeed** somewhere during the iteration. The types are verified to be the same. Therefore, the assignment should occur as intended; however it does not. If the assignment does *not* occur as intended, it should instead produce a placeholder value; however it does not.

Sorry this is so much of a mess. I feel as though I have *so little a clue what is going wrong* that I have no idea what information to include or emphasize. The best hypothesis I could come up with was that the variables declared within the scope of the loop were being held over between iterations. But if that was the case, I would expect *every `item`* to have the `.attribute` of the final `item`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this literally your code?  Aren't you overloading the name "item" here?  You're using it  both as a class and an object.  Since every "item" came from "item_list", and the comprehension is just looking itself up, isn't the first line equivalent to `item.attribute = item`?

Comment: sorry I missed this. The code is effectively `item1.attribute = item2`.

Comment: Well, if we don't have exact code, it's hard to do an analysis.  I do want to comment on "variables declared within the scope of the loop" -- Python doesn't have multiple scoping levels.  A variable is either global, or it is local to a function.  If you set "i = 3" during a loop, i will still be 3 when the loop restarts.